Is dispersion correction (D4) needed for double-hybrid functionals?
I wonder if dispersion correction (for instance D4) is needed for double hybrid (DH) functionals in case of large systems with interacting fragments (H-bonds), in particular for geometry optimization? (I vaguely remember that I might have posed this question elsewhere, and the answer was "yes", because, although there is a correlation from MP2 in DH functionals that accounts for dispersion, it is not 100%).

In general, yes. The reason is exactly as you said: double hybrids typically do not include 100% MP2 correlation, and the DFT correlation part typically does not describe dispersion (at least not its long-range component). In this case, whenever the MP2 correlation is scaled by a factor $a_C$, the $s_6$ coefficient of the DFT-D correction has to be scaled by a factor that is close to (if not exactly equal to) $1-a_C$. This is why you can see notations like B2PLYP-D3 and PWPB95-D4.
However, there are also double hybrid functionals with non-local DFT correlation, for example $\omega$B97M(2), which uses the VV10 functional to provide the dispersion part of the DFT correlation. Such functionals do not need (and cannot) be combined with dispersion corrections, because they already fully describe dispersion.

Many thanks for your response! I see your point!
